# Правильность верстки

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно будет это сверстать? Проблема именно в выравнивании данных, как их выровнять таким же образом? Т.е. чтобы независимо от левой части, правая часть всегда была выравнена по левому краю

[image: Как это сверстать?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.col1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.card {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px double#ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p>
    <span class="col1">Запрос:</span>
    <span class="col2">2 300 000р</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="col1">Выдача:</span>
    <span class="col2">2 300 000р</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="col1">Ставка:</span>
    <span class="col2">13%</span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span class="col1">Срок:</span>
    <span class="col2">36 месяцев</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: вы и сами смогли бы так сделать ! почему не сделали ?

Comment: Честно скажу, не понимал. Верстку таблиц практиковал 1 раз в жизни, и то кое-как. Все делаю на флексах и флоатах, поэтому разбирался бы долго в этом

Comment: Хм.. Я так понимаю, ты успешно решил проблему с центрированием блока с динамическим размером. Но всё же `width: 100px;` для надписей осталось...

Comment: @Qwertiy да это ничего такого, можно и margin'ами сделать) Мне идеология такой структуры была непонятна

Comment: @Alexxosipov, я там ответ без ширины уже запостил. А вот как margin'ы к делу относятся, вообще не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Без использования фиксированной ширины для надписей:

```css
.card {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 3px double #ccc;
}

p {
  display: table-row;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p>
    <span>Запрос:</span>
    <span>2 300 000 р</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Выдача:</span>
    <span>2 300 000 р</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Ставка:</span>
    <span>13%</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Срок:</span>
    <span>36 месяцев</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: я хотел на таблице пример привести но там всего 4 слова и даже намёка не было о том что надо добавлять будет новые поля так и сделал 100px

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, а локализация? Или если шрифт поменяется?

Comment: что то мне кажется это не помешает

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ширина текста поменяется и либо останется куча свободного места, либо наоборот не влезет.

Comment: но ответ очевидно устроил автора ... хотя этот вариант я не предусмотрел

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ну так я ж вроде не против. Даже плюсик поставил.